# How to work with the data that send webservice when I logging in system

Tags: angular, typescript

My webservice send me and permission from my user. My permission is an array file, json. I want to display/call this data in ather function.

```
{"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"Authentificated Successfully",
"Token":"fgfhgjhgkfgddfgggffhhfazcfdddd",
"StatusDescription":{
"permissions":["usersgetall","usersdelete","usersupdate","clientgetall",
"clientupdate","clientdelete"....]}
"role":"root"
}
```

My login function is like this:
How can I create a function that shows all permissions for my user?

```
public loginByUsernameAndPassword(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('username', username);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    urlSearchParams.append('user_uniqueIdid', '0');
    urlSearchParams.append('session_id', '0');
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.Login), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json(); 
         console.log(rs)// show Permissions[]
          if (res.StatusCode === 0 && res.Token) {
          this.currentUser = {
            username: username,
            token: res.Token
          }
          localStorage.setItem(AuthService.CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
          return true;
           } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: So what output are you getting now?  Getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reponse.json()` makes an object out of `res:Response` so you can access properties like this

```
getPermissions(responseObject:any){
    return responseObject.StatusDescription.permissions
}
```

Comment: How to call this in other function.  .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();  let permissions : any[] = res.StatusDescription.Permisions; ..} --> in console look good. But I want to create in a function this. Can you help? Thnx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "creating a function" ? I have wrapped my answer into a method